# Trying to calculate GCD in C++

Tags: c++

I think I am not calling the function or passing it correctly. Here are a couple of snippets that I am having issues with.

Using test data, 1/2 and 8/16 returns 1/2 instead of 1/1.

This is my code to calculate the GCD:

```
void Fractions::gcd(int n, int d)
{
    int a,b,c;
    a = n;
    b = d;

    while (a%b != 0)
    {
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    num = n/b;
    denom = d/b;
}
```

This is the code that calculates will add numbers from input and calculate the GCD based from those numbers:

```
Fractions Fractions::operator+(Fractions& fraction2)
{
    Fractions totalAddition;
    totalAddition.num = (num * fraction2.denom + denom * fraction2.num);
    totalAddition.denom = (denom * fraction2.denom);
    totalAddition.gcd(num, denom); // i think issue is here
    return totalAddition;
}
```

Comment: 1/2 is the irreducible form of 8/16. I don't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem here is the name of the function.

A function called `gcd` should return the Greatest Common Divisor:

```
int gcd(int n, int d) {
  int a, b, c;
  a = n;
  b = d;

  while (a % b != 0) {
    c = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }

  return b;
}
```

It doesn't need to be a member function of `Fraction` to do this - it can be a standalone function, which is better, as it makes `Fraction` more encapsulated. But you can give it an overload which digests `Fraction`:

```
int gcd(const Fraction& frac){
  return gcd(frac.numerator(), frac.denominator());
}
```

The name `gcd` is on the terse side but clear enough in context.

What your function is doing is it's simplifying a fraction, as a member function of a `Fraction` object, and overwriting that `Fraction`'s member variables. So, it should be called `simplify`, and it doesn't need to take any input:

```
void Fractions::simplify() {
  int a, b, c;
  a = num;
  b = denom;

  while (a % b != 0) {
    c = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  num = n / b;
  denom = d / b;
}
```

You might find you don't need a `gcd` function in which case `simplify` will be enough. But if you do need both functions, you can avoid some duplication of code here:

```
void Fractions::simplify() {
  int g = gcd(*this);
  num /= g;
  denom /= g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Euclidean algorithm
//if b<a the gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b)

int gcd(int a,int b)
{
 while(a!=b)
    {
        if(a>b)
          a=a-b;
        else
          b=b-a;  
    }
    return a;
 }
```

Output

```
15 12
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Optimal implementation of Euclidean Algorithm

 int gcd(int a,int b)
 {
  if(b==0)
      return a;
  else
      return gcd(b,a%b);   
 }
```

Output

```
15 12
3
```